# Quickly retrieve pvalues from multiple lm() in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a matrix (mat) with dims "13, 20000000" and the following groups

```
[1,] "wildtype"  
[2,] "wildtype"  
[3,] "wildtype"  
[4,] "wildtype"  
[5,] "wildtype"  
[6,] "wildtype"  
[7,] "wildtype"  
[8,] "wildtype"  
[9,] "wildtype"  
[10,] "wildtype"  
[11,] "mutant"    
[12,] "mutant"   
[13,] "mutant"
```

With the following R code, I run `lm()` 20M times on each data point .

`lm(mat ~ groups)` is really quick. What's taking a long time is extracting the pvalue for each model using `summary(lm1)`.

How might I speed up extracting the pvalues?

```
tvals_out <-'/tmp/tvals_lm.csv'

infile <- '/tmp/tempdata.dat'
con <- file(infile, "rb")
dim <- readBin(con, "integer", 2)
mat <- matrix( readBin(con, "numeric", prod(dim)), dim[1], dim[2])
close(con)

groups = factor(c(rep('wt', 10), rep('mut', 3)))
lm1 <- lm(mat ~ groups)

# This is the longest running bit
sum_lm1 <- summary(lm1)

num_pixels <- dim(mat)[2]

result_pvalues <- numeric(num_pixels)

result_pvalues <- vapply(sum_lm1, function(x) x$coefficients[,4][2], FUN.VALUE = 1)

write.table(result_pvalues, tvals_out, sep=',');


outCon <- file(tvals_out, "wb")
writeBin(result_pvalues, outCon)
close(outCon)
```

edit:

I've added a sample bit of data of 10 data points from the mat object

```
m <- c(28, 28, 28, 29, 33, 39, 49, 58, 63,64,30, 27, 24, 20, 17, 19, 33, 49, 56,57,36, 32, 28, 23, 20, 27, 48, 77, 96, 103,27, 26, 26, 23, 21, 23, 33, 46, 53,52,24, 20, 17, 13, 11, 14, 33, 47, 40,32,40, 46, 49, 48, 44, 49, 57, 59, 61,53,22, 24, 26, 32, 38, 39, 44, 53, 59,58,16, 16, 14, 10,7, 14, 34, 55, 62,61,28, 25, 21, 19, 22, 32, 45, 58, 64,61,28, 26, 21, 16, 14, 19, 33, 50, 59,59,17, 16, 15, 14, 17, 25, 38, 54, 61,58,11, 11, 12, 13, 16, 23, 34, 46, 51,45,22, 21, 20, 19, 16, 18, 32, 51, 50,38)

mat <- matrix(m, nrow=13)
```

Comment: Would be good if you can post a very small sample of your 20M data points (like 5-10), so we can understand what values you have, how the dataset looks like and play with the data.

Comment: @AntoniosK, I added 10 data points from my matrix. Thanks

Comment: I'd definitely go with @JasonAizkalns solution as I'm a `broom` fan and would have tried it in the first place, but I'm not sure how fast it will be when it creates a data frame with results for your 20M cases. Hope it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following function is able to extract p-values from a fit on a 13x20,000,000 matrix (like yours) in about 25 seconds.

```
pvalOnly2 <- function(fit) {
    # get estimates
    est <- fit$coefficients[fit$qr$pivot, ]

    # get R: see stats:::summary.lm to see how this is calculated
    p1 <- 1L:(fit$rank)
    R <- diag(chol2inv(fit$qr$qr[p1, p1, drop = FALSE]))

    # get residual sum of squares for each
    resvar <- colSums(fit$residuals^2) / fit$df.residual
    # R is same for each coefficient, resvar is same within each model 
    se <- sqrt(outer(R, resvar))

    pt(abs(est / se), df = fit$df.residual, lower.tail = FALSE) * 2
}
```

This calculates the same p-values as calling `summary` (or Benjamin's `pvalOnly` function). However, it skips all the other steps that `summary` performs for each model, making it much faster. (Note that Benjamin's `pvalOnly` calls `vcov`, which in turn calls `summary`, which is why it does not save time).

On a small matrix this is about 30 times faster than summary:

```
m <- c(28, 28, 28, 29, 33, 39, 49, 58, 63,64,30, 27, 24, 20, 17, 19, 33, 49, 56,57,36, 32, 28, 23, 20, 27, 48, 77, 96, 103,27, 26, 26, 23, 21, 23, 33, 46, 53,52,24, 20, 17, 13, 11, 14, 33, 47, 40,32,40, 46, 49, 48, 44, 49, 57, 59, 61,53,22, 24, 26, 32, 38, 39, 44, 53, 59,58,16, 16, 14, 10,7, 14, 34, 55, 62,61,28, 25, 21, 19, 22, 32, 45, 58, 64,61,28, 26, 21, 16, 14, 19, 33, 50, 59,59,17, 16, 15, 14, 17, 25, 38, 54, 61,58,11, 11, 12, 13, 16, 23, 34, 46, 51,45,22, 21, 20, 19, 16, 18, 32, 51, 50,38)

mat <- matrix(m, nrow=13)
groups <- rep(c("wildtype", "mutant"), times = c(10, 3))

fit <- lm(mat ~ groups)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(summary = do.call("cbind", lapply(summary(fit), function(f) coef(f)[, 4])),
               pvalOnly2(fit))
```

with results:

```
Unit: microseconds
           expr      min       lq     mean    median        uq      max neval cld
        summary 3383.085 3702.238 3978.110 3919.0755 4147.4015 5475.223   100   b
 pvalOnly2(fit)   81.538   91.541  136.903  137.1275  157.5535  459.415   100  a
```

The speed advantage is much larger, however, when there are more models you're fitting. On a matrix of 13x1000, it has about a 300x advantage. And on my machine, when there are 20 million columns, it calculates the p-values in 25 seconds- twice as fast as the `fit <- lm(mat ~ groups)` step, in fact.

```
> mat <- mat[, rep(1:10, 2e6)]   # just replicating same coefs
> dim(mat)
[1]       13 20000000
> system.time(fit <- lm(mat ~ groups))
   user  system elapsed 
 37.272  10.296  58.372 
> system.time(pvals <- pvalOnly2(fit))
   user  system elapsed 
 21.945   1.889  24.322
```

The resulting p-values are correct (same as you'd get out of summary):

```
> dim(pvals)
[1]        2 20000000
> pvals[, 1:10]
                      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]         [,4]        [,5]       [,6]
(Intercept)    0.006048267 0.01234835 0.02655251 0.0004555316 0.001004109 0.01608319
groupswildtype 0.129224604 0.22806894 0.88113522 0.2064583345 0.103624361 0.84642990
                       [,7]      [,8]       [,9]        [,10]
(Intercept)    0.0004630405 0.1386393 0.05107805 5.042796e-05
groupswildtype 0.2717139022 0.1539826 0.66351492 5.942893e-02
```

(By the way, profiling shows that almost all the running time in the function is spent in the `pt` function- since that's done in C this is about as fast as it can be made in any language).

In response to your comment, you can also get the per-model p-value (from the F-statistic) with the following function, which is a similar speed to `pvalOnly2`:

```
modelPvalOnly <- function(fit) {
    f <- t(fit$fitted.values)
    if (attr(fit$terms, "intercept"))  {
        mss <- rowSums((f - rowMeans(f)) ^ 2)
        numdf <- fit$rank - 1
    } else {
        mss <- rowSums(f ^ 2)
        numdf <- fit$rank
    }

    resvar <- colSums(fit$residuals^2) / fit$df.residual
    fstat <- (mss / numdf) / resvar
    pval <- pf(fstat, numdf, fit$df.residual, lower.tail = FALSE)
    pval
}
```

Comment: That looks really promising. I'll try it later today

Comment: It is indeed orders of magnitude faster than what I was previously doing.  Thank you. Is it possible to also extract the p-value  for the whole model if using multiple fixed effects?

Comment: @user521469 Yes- I have edited such a function into my answer. Note that you can also have those functions return the standard errors, t-statistics, f-statistics, etc (since they are calculated on the way to computing the p-values).

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It has been a huge help

Comment: @user521469 Very glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

How about giving the [`broom`](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom) package a try?

```
install.packages(broom)
library(broom)

tidy(lm(mat ~ groups))
#    response        term   estimate std.error  statistic      p.value
# 1        Y1 (Intercept)  27.000000  7.967548  3.3887465 6.048267e-03
# 2        Y1    groupswt  14.900000  9.084402  1.6401740 1.292246e-01
# 3        Y2 (Intercept)  23.333333  7.809797  2.9877004 1.234835e-02
# 4        Y2    groupswt  11.366667  8.904539  1.2765026 2.280689e-01
# 5        Y3 (Intercept)  44.000000 17.192317  2.5592828 2.655251e-02
# ...and more...
```

Then to extract only the results for `groupswt` (note: various ways to accomplish this...):

```
subset(tidy(lm(mat ~ groups)), term == "groupswt")[, c(1,6)]
#    response    p.value
# 2        Y1 0.12922460
# 4        Y2 0.22806894
# 6        Y3 0.88113522
# 8        Y4 0.20645833
# 10       Y5 0.10362436
# 12       Y6 0.84642990
# 14       Y7 0.27171390
# 16       Y8 0.15398258
# 18       Y9 0.66351492
# 20      Y10 0.05942893
```

Comment: broom looks nice. I may use it in the future. However it seems to be quite a bit slower

Answer (score 3):

I'm having a hard time imagining what would be faster than `summary`.  In the interest of trying, I wrote a quick diddy to calculate the p-value from the coefficients and standard errors.  I also tried the `broom` approach.  Results based on the sample data are below

```
m <- c(28, 28, 28, 29, 33, 39, 49, 58, 63,64,30, 27, 24, 20, 17, 19, 33, 49, 56,57,36, 32, 28, 23, 20, 27, 48, 77, 96, 103,27, 26, 26, 23, 21, 23, 33, 46, 53,52,24, 20, 17, 13, 11, 14, 33, 47, 40,32,40, 46, 49, 48, 44, 49, 57, 59, 61,53,22, 24, 26, 32, 38, 39, 44, 53, 59,58,16, 16, 14, 10,7, 14, 34, 55, 62,61,28, 25, 21, 19, 22, 32, 45, 58, 64,61,28, 26, 21, 16, 14, 19, 33, 50, 59,59,17, 16, 15, 14, 17, 25, 38, 54, 61,58,11, 11, 12, 13, 16, 23, 34, 46, 51,45,22, 21, 20, 19, 16, 18, 32, 51, 50,38)

mat <- matrix(m, nrow=13)
groups <- rep(c("wildtype", "mutant"), times = c(10, 3))

fit <- lm(mat ~ groups)


#* Using summary
do.call("cbind", lapply(summary(fit), function(f) coef(f)[, 4]))


#* Directly calculating p-value
pvalOnly <- function(fit){
  pt(abs(coef(fit) / sqrt(diag(vcov(fit)))), 
     df = fit$df.residual, 
     lower.tail = FALSE) * 2
}

pvalDirect <- pvalOnly(fit)


#* Using broom
library(broom)
tidy(fit)$p.value



library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  summary = do.call("cbind", lapply(summary(fit), function(f) coef(f)[, 4])),
  direct = pvalOnly(fit),
  broom = tidy(fit)$p.value
)
```

As you can see, in this very small representation, using `summary` is still a wee bit faster than the direct calculation. `broom` adds a lot of time (not surprising, since it's doing a lot of work to tidy up things you aren't trying to capture)

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 summary 1.685857 1.744652 1.969350 1.804914 1.877931 4.929129   100  a 
  direct 1.860630 1.933501 2.184573 2.047279 2.160765 6.442852   100  a 
   broom 5.303015 5.557257 6.060014 5.818830 5.999028 9.879372   100   b
```

Comment: Thanks for benchmarking the different methods. I repeated on a large dataset and found the direct method to be very slightly quicker (~2%) than the using summary. Maybe I need to move from R to something like c or maybe numpy

Comment: Your `pvalOnly` function is calling `stats:::vcov.mlm`, which actually calls `summary.mlm` itself- so no wonder it's not any faster than calling summary! I show an alternative for directly computing the p-values in my answer below, which is 30x faster on this example and can do the 20,000,000 case in ~25 seconds.

Comment: Wow. Awesome. User522469. I'd suggest accepting David's answer over mine.

Comment: @Benjamin I accepted David's answer, but thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

I've got a script where I do a bunch of regressions and then collect the coefficients including the p-values.  Here's what it looks like

```
library(data.table)
summ<-summary(lm1)$coefficients
coeffs<-data.table(summ)
coeffs[,coef:=row.names(summ)]
setnames(coeffs,c("estimate", "stderr","t","p","coef"))
```